# Can I wire new CT410A Thermostat, based on the original Tstat(90s Nortron) wiring?

Tags: thermostat

ORIGINAL THERMOSTAT; Single pole 90s NORTRON connected to baseboard heater,which has no fan.

WIRING- Red wire (connected to single black wire in electrical box) was screwed into Tstat connection marked "NORM CLOSED"
Black wire (connected to two black wires in electrical box) was screwed into Tstat connection marked "COMMON"
Replacement CT410A has two black wires marked L1 and T1.
Can I use original wiring as guide or do I have to determine line and load wires using multimeter?

Comment: Pictures of the wiring diagrams on the two devices would be most helpful.